# </script> within a JavaScript string in a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have an app that can generate all sorts of things into the JavaScript strings put on the page. I thought all the escaping were ok, but then I came across a weird problem that I couldn't really find a reason for:

Shouldn't this be legal in an html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("hello </script>");
</script>
```

'Legal' meaning that it would produce an alert with `hello </script>`.

Apparently both moz and chrome, on my box at least, cuts the scripting off after the `</script>` part of the alert string, producing no alert and a messy output. Has anyone run into this, is this a browser bug?

Comment: Put a slash `alert("hello <\/script>");`

Comment: Take a look at this great post where is good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to "escape" character "<" and ">" for javascript string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779959/is-it-necessary-to-escape-character-and-for-javascript-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The HTML parses it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("hello 
</script>
");
</script>
```

With the first occurrence of `</script>` closing the open `<script>` element. The common way of avoiding this issue is by including a `\` before the `/` character in the string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("hello <\/script>");
</script>
```

This works because the `\` escape character will prevent the browser from recognizing `<\/script>` as an end tag. Normally `\` is used as an escape sequence in JavaScript strings, but as there's no `\/` sequence, the escape character is ignored and the string evaluates as `'</script'>`.

This issue can generally be avoided if you follow the good practice of keeping all of your javascript in external `.js` files. That said, it's common to see this sort of escaping used for [local script fallbacks for unresponsive CDNs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/139380/7865).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that html and script parsing work at different layers.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('hello <'+'/script>');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('hello <\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: Explain something that what you did here, don't just post your codes, will help people who don't understand what you did over here...

Answer (score 0):

You should do like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    alert('hello </script>');
// ]]>
</script>
```

To prevent the parsing.