# Form Submit Not Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testForm").submit(sendPost)
});

function sendPost() {
  alert('Submitted');
}
```

```html
<form id="testForm">
  <input type="text" ID="txtDescription"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Clicking the Submit button does not fire the alert. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

The *original* code had the reference to jquery lib *inside* the javascript, *without* script tags. That does *not* load the external resource. Since jquery doesn't load, the click event doesn't get registered.

One solution to this issue is to reference the external js file in your HTML, with a `<script>` tag:

**HTML Solution**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm">
  <input type="text" ID="txtDescription"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
</form>
```

and remove the reference from your .js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testForm").submit(sendPost) 
});

function sendPost() {
  alert('Submitted');
}
```

**Jquery Solution**

A solution for jquery to load some *other* js file, if you don't want to put `<script src=...` in the HTML, is to put the following in your .js. This requires that jquery is already loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append($('<script src="/path/to/script/foo.min.js"></script>'));
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42378530/209942

Comment: It is not an incorrect syntax. `src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"` is perfectly valid, but it does not load a script. It just assigns the string to the variable `src`. Not loading jQuery results in `$` not being defined (or being something different then jQuery).

Comment: If you do not write a `<script src=...` in the html, then the only way to execute the `$(document).ready(function(){ $('body').append(...) })` is if it is an inline script (`<script> ... </script>`) and if this is the case then the given code won't work, because  the `</script>` in the script would end the script, and that would result in a syntax error. So your `Jquery Solution` is not correct.

Comment: The jquery method could be used to load some other js. But yes, it needs jquery to be loaded.

Comment: It's not about jQuery. If the given script is placed as an inline script like `<script>console.log('<script src="/path/to/script/foo.min.js"></script>')</script>`, then the `</script>` within the string, will be the actual end tag, so to the browser the script would look like `console.log('<script src="/path/to/script/foo.min.js">` which is an incomplete script, and as of that a syntax error. You need to break the `</script> ` in the string so that it won't be recognized as and tag by the html parser: `<script>console.log('<script src="/path/to/script/foo.min.js"><' + '/script>')</script>`

Comment: [</script> within a JavaScript string in a <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488830/script-within-a-javascript-string-in-a-script-tag)

Comment: @t.niese The script isn't inline.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as is. You have to click on the button to submit it. But looking at the I believe, you want to submit the the form on document ready.

You can do it in following way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testForm").submit(sendPost);
  $('#submit').click();
});
    
function sendPost() {
  alert('Submitted');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm">
  <input type="text" ID="txtDescription"><br>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save" /> 
</form>
```