# How do I properly escape inline Javascript in a <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I'm writing a server-side function for a framework that will let me inline a Javascript file. It takes the filename as input, and its output would be like this:

```
<script>
   /* contents of Javascript file */
</script>
```

**How do I escape the contents of the Javascript file safely?**

I am particularly worried if the file contains something like `</script>`. If the input Javascript file has syntax errors, I still want it to escape correctly. I also realise that XHTML expects some entities to be encoded, whereas HTML doesn't.

There are a lot of questions similar to this asking about [how to escape string literals or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779959/247696). But I want something that can handle the general case, so that I can write a tool for the general case.

<sub>(I realise inlining potentially untrusted Javascript isn't the best idea, so no need to spend time discussing that.)</sub>

Comment: You can always use a data URI: `<script src="data:application/javascript,..."`></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a work in progress, let me know if I've missed a corner case!

The answer is different depending on whether you're using XHTML or HTML.

### 1. XHTML with `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` header

In this case, you can simply XML escape any entities, turning this file:

```
console.log("Example Javascript file");
console.log(1</script>2/);
console.log("That previous line prints false");
```

To this:

```
<script>
console.log(&quot;Example Javascript file&quot;);
console.log(1&lt;/script&gt;2/);
console.log(&quot;That previous line prints false&quot;);
</script>
```

Note that if you're using XHTML with a different `Content-Type` header, then different browsers may behave differently, and I haven't researched it, so I would recommend fixing the `Content-Type` header.

### 2. HTML

Unfortunately, I know of no way to escape it properly in this case (without at least parsing the Javascript). Replacing all instances of `/` with `\/` would cause some Javascript to break, including the previous example.

The best that I can recommend is that you search for `</script` case-insensitively and throw an exception if you find it. If you're only dealing with string literals or JSON, substitute all instances of `/` with `\/`.

Some Javascript minifiers might deal with `</script` in a safe manner perhaps, let me know if you find one.

Comment: Providing one knows that it's the body of the script element that's being escaped. then based on the HTML5 parser algorithm, I believe that substituting `</script` (and all upper-case variants) when the next character is one of U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION (tab), U+000A LINE FEED (LF), U+000C FORM FEED (FF), U+0020 SPACE, U+002F SOLIDUS (/), U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (>)  with `<\/script` should work for the HTML case.

Comment: You don't really have to escape quotes in XHTML; escaping `&` and `<` is enough. As long as you're absolutely sure the document has an XML file type.

Comment: @Alohci: but replacing it with `<\/script` will cause a Javascript syntax error where there may not have been one before. I admit that the Javascript `1</script>/` is a bit contrived, but it is valid Javascript and I would like to find a way that would never break the Javascript, just to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Ah yes. I see what you're saying now. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't HTML be fine with `</   script>` closing tag too?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I tried it on Firefox, and Firefox does not parse `</ script>`. Can you find a browser that does?